# How Appium server is differ from Selenium server

Tags: selenium, appium

We are using Appium server for executing test cases in Android device . Selenium client library sends the Json protocol to respective driver exe file then driver exe file send the request to the  browser. I would like to know  in Appium why can't client libraries directly send the Json request to UIautomator2 or XCUITEST .why request should be send it to Appium server and Appium server is forwarding it to UIAutomator2 . or XCUITEST